# Variable in C program behaving weirdly in Visual studio

Tags: c, visual-studio-2019

I created a test project with the following code to check for problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

    int main(void) {
    int a;
    scanf_s("%d", &a);
    printf("%d", &a);
}
```

I enter the input of 1 and it gives me random numbers of 7 digits like this

[image]

and this

[image]

can someone help please

Comment: I don't know how to turn up the warning level on Visual Studio, but if you do, hopefully it'll tell you what's wrong.

Comment: To turn on warnings, right click your project and use the C/C++ tab and enable `/W3` warnings. See [Configuring your compiler: Warning and error levels](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/configuring-your-compiler-warning-and-error-levels/) and [/w, /W0, /W1, /W2, /W3, /W4, /w1, /w2, /w3, /w4, /Wall, /wd, /we, /wo, /Wv, /WX (Warning level)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-option-warning-level?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `scanf` family of functions needs addresses because it *writes* to those addresses to populate the variables.

Since the `printf` family only needs the *values* (although, for C strings, that's the same thing), you should get rid of the `&` operator:

```
printf("%d", a);
```

Otherwise you're trying to print out the address of that variable rather than the value.

Answer (score 1):

You're printing out the value of the memory address to `a`, not the value of what the variable `a` is holding.

You'll want to use the variable directly like:

```
printf("%d", a);
```

to print the actual value of `a`.

The [CPP reference wiki](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) also contains good information for C functions if you want to see how they should be used.

Comment: (technically C doesn't have references, they are attempting to output the *address of* `a` in memory and invoking undefined behavior attempting to output the pointer as a decimal value)